# How to extract content from all DIV's with class="sco" using DOM and PHP

Tags: php, dom

I have got multiple DIV's with content in a php file : div class="sco".

The following code works very well but it only extracts the content from the first DIV. How can I extract content from all DIV's ?

Thank you in advance.

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www..../include/test.php');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$finder = new DomXPath($doc);
$node = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, 'sco')]");
print_r($doc->saveHTML($node->item(0)));
```

Comment: Thanks guys. It works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the last line, you're accessing only the first item (index 0): `$node->item(0)`

Instead, loop the `$node` and print each item:

```
$node = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, 'sco')]");
foreach($node as $item){
    print_r($doc->saveHTML($item));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate over your [`DOMNodeList`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) object:

```
<?php

$html = '
<div class="sco">a</div>
<div class="sco">b</div>
<div class="sco">c</div>
';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$finder = new DomXPath($doc);
$node = $finder->query("//*[contains(@class, 'sco')]");

for($i=0;$i<$node->length;$i++)
{
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($node->item($i)->nodeValue);
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

*Output:*

```
string(1) "a"
string(1) "b"
string(1) "c"
```